# EF6 Inserting Composite key record errors

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have an interesting conundrum occurring that i am hoping others will be able to assist in shedding some light upon.

When inserting a new entry using EF6 to a table that has a composite key made up of two Guids where one member is to be assigned from the DB while the other has its value supplied by the application i am getting mixed responses.

For one table the insertion occurs without any issue while for another with the exact same key and identity column setup the insertion fails with a message 'InvalidOperationException: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ID'.' Below are the (simplified) classes with their configuration setups

The Class that fails to insert :

```
public class User
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Guid OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public String PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public String Salt { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

    // <inconsequential members omitted> 
}


public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(u => new { u.CompanyId, u.ID });
        Property(u => u.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        Property(u => u.UserName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        Property(u => u.PasswordHash).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        Property(u => u.Salt).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        HasRequired(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.Users).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        HasRequired(c => c.Organization).WithMany(c => c.Users).HasForeignKey(p => p.OrganizationID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        // < inconsequential members omitted>
    }
}
```

The Class that inserts without issue :

```
public class AdditionalInformation
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomFieldId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId{ get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    // <inconsequential members omitted> 
}

public class AdditionalInformationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AdditionalInformation>
{
    public AdditionalInformationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(ai => new { ai.CompanyId, ai.ID });
        Property(u => u.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasOptional(ai => ai.User).WithMany(u => u.UserAdditionalInformations).HasForeignKey(ai => new { ai.CompanyId, ai.UserID });

        // <inconsequential members omitted> 
    }
}
```

Simple test i have been using :

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.First(f => f.Company.Subdomain.StartsWith("demo"));
    var customField = context.CustomFields.First(f => f.CompanyId == user.CompanyId);

    context.Users.Add(new User() { CompanyId = user.CompanyId, PasswordHash = "hash", Salt = "salt", UserName = "anew@entry.com" });
    context.AdditionalInformations.Add(new UserAdditionalInformation() { CustomFieldID = customField.ID, CompanyId = user.CompanyId, UserID = user.ID });
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

As you can see, both classes have an ID member as well as a CompanyId member. They both have the Key defined as { CompanyId, Id } and the DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity on the ID member.

I am very confused as to why when an instance of the `AdditionalInformation` class is persisted to the DB through the DbContext, the record is created without issue while the `User` class throws the 'InvalidOperationException: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ID'.' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix my own problem but cannot explain how the fix has had the effect it has.

The User object had a navigation property to another table which did not expose the FK column on the User object. Once the inferred column was exposed, the insertion problem went away.

I found this by accident since while trying to understand the problem i noticed that this one FK was not explicitly exposed and so did so, then found that my unit test started working after the change.